# How to do proximity search between phrases in SOLR?

Tags: solr, lucene

How can I do "X M" AND "Z K" in distance of 10 words or so?

I saw it in word level "foo bar"~4 ([proximity link](http://www.solrtutorial.com/solr-query-syntax.html))

Can I do proximity search in pharses level and not in word level ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind being a bit looser on your matching, you could always just do this: `"X M Z K"~10`.  That would match what you want.  It would, however, also match some other things like: "X A A M Z A A A K".  If you can tolerate that, then there is the easy answer.  You might also look into the edismax query parser's [`pf2` and `ps2`](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax#qs_.28Query_Phrase_Slop.29) parameters, see if those are something you can use to get close enough.

The [surround query parser](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SurroundQueryParser), by the way, is designed around using SpanQueries.  It seems like a query like: `{!surround} 10W(1N(X, M), 1N(Z, K))` would work here, but it seems surround doesn't support nested parentheses, unless I'm missing something.

If those aren't adequate for your needs, I believe you will need to build the query through the Lucene API directly, rather than through Solr query syntax.  A combination of `SpanQuery`s would do the job, like:

```java
SpanQuery termX = new SpanTermQuery(new Term("fieldName", "X"));
SpanQuery termM = new SpanTermQuery(new Term("fieldName", "M"));
SpanQuery termZ = new SpanTermQuery(new Term("fieldName", "Z"));
SpanQuery termK = new SpanTermQuery(new Term("fieldName", "K"));
SpanQuery phraseXM = new SpanNearQuery(new SpanQuery[] {termX, termM}, 0, true);
SpanQuery phraseZK = new SpanNearQuery(new SpanQuery[] {termZ, termK}, 0, true);
SpanQuery finalQuery = new SpanNearQuery(new SpanQuery[] {phraseXM, phraseZK}, 10, false);
```

Comment: And how would you pass a SpanQuery to solr ?